# Processed not before timestamp Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there an out-of-the-box mechanism in Kafka to produce a record that shall not be processed **before** a given timestamp regardless of the contents of the topic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't; Kafka consumes by offset, not by timestamps. But that doesn't prevent your consumer from handing off messages to some secondary worker "priority queue" ordered by timestamp backed by some scheduler thread that checks for the next event to be processed

Only problem is that if you process a message offset "O+1" with time "T-1" while waiting on message "O@T", and your consumer crashes and loses that in-memory queue, then you're effectively skipping messages (committing O+1 without processing O)

Depending on your application, this might be okay, since you could reproduce  records again to queue them. You can also seek to specific offsets or get (approximate) offsets by a particular timestamp (which defaults to time the record is produced)